# why method return zero size of list<Country>

Tags: java, android, list

i have this code to get information from API

```
public class MainModel implements InterfacesSpace.MAIN_MODEL {

List<CountryModel> ARRAYS;



 @Override
public List<CountryModel> Weather_Information() {

    final Call<CountryModel.ResultModel> connection = INSTANCE_API_SERVICE.loadItems();
    connection.enqueue(new Callback<CountryModel.ResultModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<CountryModel.ResultModel> call, Response<CountryModel.ResultModel> response) {

            countryModels = response.body().getCountryModels();

            for (int i = 0; i < countryModels.size(); i++) {


                CountryModel ye = new CountryModel("","","");
                ye.setCountry(countryModels.get(i).getCountry());
                ye.setCity(countryModels.get(i).getCity());
                ye.setDegree(countryModels.get(i).getDegree());
                ARRAYS.add(ye);
                //Log.e("TESTSAIF" ,ARRAYS.get(0).getCity());

                //  Log.e("array size ", String.valueOf(ARRAYS.size()));
                //  Log.e("Size", String.valueOf(arrayList.size()));
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<CountryModel.ResultModel> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("error",t.getMessage());
        }

    });

  //  return ARRAYS.get(0);


    return ARRAYS;

}
```

and in my presnter class this function

```
 @Override
public void Request_weather_Information() {

    MODEL_INSTANCE.Establishing_DB_Communication();

    Log.e("test", String.valueOf(MODEL_INSTANCE.getsizearry()));
    // Log.e("Size", String.valueOf(MODEL_INSTANCE.Weather_Information().getCity()));
}
```

the error message is : 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference 
why this happend

Comment: @Override
    public int getsizearry() {
        return ARRAYS.size();
    }

Answer (score 1):

If the exception is coming from the for loop, `countryModels` could be null. if `response.body().getCountryModels();` isn't returning an instance for `countryModels`, calling `.size()` on `countryModels` would be giving you a null pointer.

If the exception is coming from the `Request_weather_Information()` method or the `getsizearry()` method, try passing `ARRAYS` into the `RequestWeatherInformation()` method and `getsizearry()` method, such as `RequestWeatherInformation( List<CountryModel> ARRAYS)`. Since those methods are declared in a seperate class they won't have access to the ARRAYS size from the other class unless you pass it.

Comment: i try to print size of ARRAYS not size of CountryModel instance

Comment: i call this method @Override public int getsizearry() { return ARRAYS.size(); }

Comment: any body help me please and save my day

Comment: you're also calling .size() on countryModels in the for loop condition.  So when you comment out the log statements the code runs fine?

Comment: when i try to print ARRAY.size after for loop that work fine and print 6 thats fine but when i call the method to return arraysize error problem show

Comment: so the exception is coming from the Request_weather_Information() method? Is the getsizearry() method declared in the MainModel class or elsewhere?

Comment: update : when i edit my code to  List<CountryModel> ARRAYS = new ArrayList<>();
Log.e print arraysize is 0 ! but it 1 how i can solve this issue please

Comment: so the exception is coming from the Request_weather_Information() method? try passing ARRAYS into the RequestWeatherInformation() method like  RequestWeatherInformation( List<CountryModel> ARRAYS).  If that method is declared in a seperate class it won't have access to the ARRAYS size unless you pass it.